# Resolving dependencies in ServiceRoute with Unity on an ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, rest

I have a WCF service that I expose via REST using ServiceRoute in an ASP.NET MVC project:

```
routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Rest", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ServeiInventaris)));
```

In my controllers, I use Unity to resolve dependencies. Is there a way to integrate Unity with ServiceRoute to let it resolve my dependencies (the dependencies of the REST service)?

Comment: I tried implementing a WebServiceHostFactory using unity to resolve the WebService (which I pass on to the returned WebServiceHost), but it didn't work as expected. now I user DependencyResolver.Current inside the service constructor to get the current DependencyResolver. It's not the best solution but it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The solution is custom service host factory. Here is descibed complete solution. [Neovolve blog](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/05/15/Unity-dependency-injection-for-WCF-services-e28093-Part-1.aspx) We are using it successfully for one year.